# Breaking line inside inline maths seperated by comma

Tags: inline

I am trying to write a huge inline math expression `$S_{new} =\left\lbrace(x_{k} + N(\mu_{x},\sigma),y_{k} + N(\mu_{y},\sigma))\allowbreak,(x_{k}+1 + N(\mu_{x},\sigma),y_{k}+1 + N(\mu_{y},\sigma))..\right\rbrace \forall \ k  \in \left\lbrace1,2,....,(p-2)\right\rbrace \ and\ S_{new} \in S$.` and it is overflowing margin, how can i prevent it from doing so and break line

Comment: Don't use `\left`...`\right`. Instead if `\bigl`...`\bigr` (by adding [`\usepackage{amsmath}`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to your preamble). Then also break your math up in components separated at the `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enclose some math between `\left` and `\right` no line break can happen: it's a math mode analog of `\mbox` (besides doing its main job of sizing fences).

Avoid long inline set description: they're difficult to follow. If you need one, don't add useless `\left` and `\right`. The `\allowbreak` token should go *after* the comma. Ellipsis should be `\dots` (or variant thereof) and textual subscripts should be in upright type. Remember to load `amsmath`.

```
$S_{\mathrm{new}} = \lbrace
  (x_{k} + N(\mu_{x},\sigma), y_{k} + N(\mu_{y},\sigma)),\allowbreak
  (x_{k}+1 + N(\mu_{x},\sigma), y_{k}+1 + N(\mu_{y},\sigma)),
  \dotsc % dots for commas
\rbrace$
for all $k\in\lbrace 1,2,\dots,(p-2)\rbrace$ and $S_{\mathrm{new}} \in S$.
```

Indenting the code like this may help you deciphering it and checking for unbalanced parentheses. Note that there are *three* distinct formulas;  `\forall` should better be textual (but this is personal opinion).

Comment: does LaTeX allow a line break before the final period there? (`... \in S$.`)

Comment: @JasonS No, there's no feasible break point.

Comment: now we just need MathJax and KaTeX to do the same....

Comment: @JasonS That's what I was thinking to.